# Check selection and compare to list for python

Tags: python, python-2.7

What I am trying to do is check that an input from the user (using `raw_input`) is a valid option within a global list. Below is what I have up to this point.

```
def car():
    print "You have selected the 'car' option.",
    print "Are you sure this is what you want?"
    car_sure = raw_input("Enter Yes or No: ").lower()

    if car_sure == "yes":
        car_brand_choice()

    elif car_sure == "no":
        print "You no longer want a car. Taking you back to select your vehicle type."
        type()

    else:
         dead("Not a valid option. You lose your vehicle purchasing opportunity.")

def car_brand_choice(): 
    print "These are the car brands I can provide to you."
    print "\n".join(car_brands)
    selection = raw_input("Now is your chance to pick which brand you want. ").title()
    print "You selected %s\n" %selection
    print "I have to verify your selection is valid.\n"

    if selection in car_brands:
        print "Valid selection. You may continue."

    else:
        print "Not valid selection."
        print "Go back and select a valid brand.\n"
        car_brand_choice()


start()
```

The verification will then be used to select a different valid brand or allow the user to proceed with current brand.
The code is formatted properly in Notepad++, I hope. I just don't know how to get the proper formatting to show up here. 
I'm sure there is something similar out there already but I just could not find it.

Comment: Fix the indentation and remove all the irrelavent part. Make [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems as if you are a beginner.

The thing that you need to solve your problem is `in`.

```
selection = raw_input("Now is your chance to pick which brand you want. ")
print "You selected ", selection
if selection in car_brands:
    print "It is in the list"
else:
    print "Its not in the list"
```

Add this in your `car_brand_choice()`.
For further readings, check the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html)

Answer (score 1):

You may simply use the [`in`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#in) operator.

```
>>> 'BMW' in car_brands
True
>>> 'bmw' in car_brands
False
```

As you can see, it's case sensitive. In your case, you could do something like:

```
if selection.lower() in car_brands:
    print "Valid car brand."
else
    print "Invalid car brand."
```

Also, I would remove both instances of `'\n'` from `car_brands`. That is not a car brand. You should handle line formatting somewhere else.